# Automatic update the file in cloud whenever database of java standalone application is changed

Tags: azure, java, cloud, entra-id, azure-networking

I have created a java standalone application for windows and used SQLite as database and now i want to connect this application with azure so that database can be saved on cloud an anyone help me how to do this ??

whenever database will update it should also update the file in cloud how to achieve this ..

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic way to have your SQLite database backed up to Azure, you will need to do something to create a process to do this, such as:

- Altering your application code to write transactions both to your local SQLite instance and a DB instance running in Azure (either on a VM, or using the PaaS services for MSSQL, MYSQL or Postgres)
- Writing a script that runs as a scheduled tasks and copies the SQLite file up to Azure storage
- Running the Azure Backup agent on your network and having it backup the SQLite DB to Azure backup